# Different EARs using common services. Should I use remote calls, or package them as local?

Tags: performance, jboss, jakarta-ee, local

I have multiple EJB3 ears deployed on jboss server. One of them is an application containing common services exposed as remote. Now all other ears use those services via remote and it seems to be realy painful for performance.

What can i do to overcome this? Can I make those services @Local and package this jar to every single application to allow them to be used via @Local not @Remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JavaEE tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbmg.html#bnbmj), the client of a `@Local` bean "must run in the same JVM as the enterprise bean it accesses."

So you should have no problem using local calls between different deployed applications on the same server.

Are you sure this is the cause of your performance problems, though?

Answer (score 0):

I disagree. See this thread as it provides an excellent description of why you shouldn't: http://www.coderanch.com/t/79249/Websphere/Local-EJB-calls-separate-ear

The only way, normally, to make local calls between ears is to make cross-classloader calls. Not pretty.

You can get around this by having a single classloader per server (versus scoped by ear). Also a bad idea for security/isolation reasons.

You should use remote calls between ears. Some Java EE implementations optimize these calls to be more efficient when calling within the same jvm.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you, you cannot inject an ejb session bean from another ear and in the same jvm using local interface.

if you have two ear you must use the remote interface, and using:
 @EJB(lookup ="JNDI_BEAN_NAME")